# Could a sling launcher be used on Mars?

Tags: mars, atmospheric-drag, advanced-propulsion, feasibility, launch-system

A sling launcher (discussed in [this write-up](http://home.earthlink.net/~geoffrey.landis/Lunar_Sling_Launcher.pdf) by Landis) is a tower with a motor that spins a hub with two or more cables attached. Payload(s) are attached to the end of one or more cables and counterweights to others. Once the hub is spinning, the cables are reeled out a number of kilometers until the angular momentum at their tips is so high the payload reaches orbit after it is released.

[image: schematic of sling launcher]

The paper linked to discusses its use on the Moon. I can see why drag makes the system unusable on Earth, but the atmosphere of Mars is only 1% that of Earth. There must be a density below which the atmospheric drag is manageable. Actually, considering the high efficiency of sling launchers as a launch system, and their relative simplicity, perhaps it could be worth dealing with quite a bit of drag, considering the savings on propellant.

Is the atmosphere of Mars too thick to make sling launchers practical?

Edit: Sensibly, several people have mentioned that the cable for this launcher is impossible using current materials, including 2012rcampion's answer, which lays out the calculations that show that. The paper referenced based most calculations on carbon nanotube cables. This technology seems feasible if still distant, so let us assume it would be used in this case. From the paper:

> The ultimate tensile strength of fullerene nanotubes is predicted by
>   theory to be well over 100 GPa [9], with measured values on individual
>   tubes approaching this value. Allowing an engineering factor of 5
>   (including the added strands for cross-connections, discussed below),
>   the material should allow a working stress of 20 GPa. A mass of one
>   thousand kg at 11.5 gravities (110 m/sec2 ) results in a force on the
>   cable of 112,000 N, as shown in table 1, so the required cross-section
>   of the cable is 0.00389 cm2 (0.389 square millimeters) per ton of
>   end-mass. (More likely, this will be in the form of a number of
>   separate cables which sum to a total cross-sectional area .389 mm2 ).
>   The density of fullerene nanotubes is 1.3 gr/cm3 . The mass of the 50
>   km cable itself is then about 25 kg, and it is clear that neglecting
>   the mass of the cable itself in the calculation was justifiable. The
>   counterweight cable carries half the mass, but at half the
>   acceleration, and half the length, so the counterweight cable has a
>   total mass of about 13kg. An ultimate strength of 20 GPa may be
>   optimistic for a realistic material. If the working stress is reduced
>   to 10 GPa, the cable cross-section is doubled, and the mass increases
>   to 51 kg and 15 kg for the launch cable and the counterweight
>   respectively

Comment: I think the major issue would be the launch cable. The analysis shows that with existing materials, a cable mass of 2,500 kg would be sufficient to launch a 1,000 kg object; only with fullerene nanotubes does this turn into a more practical 50 kg. Remember, Mars escape velocity is about double that of the moon, requiring a cable four times as strong. I think that makes existing materials entirely infeasible.

Comment: @raptortech97 this is true, and I think it is necessary to assume carbon nanotube cables in order to usefully answer the question. I'm about to put in the relevant quote from the paper. But that doesn't seem out of order for a project that couldn't be realized for several decades anyhow. [Rice University](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XDJC64tDR0)  is spinning nanotube thread now, after all.

Comment: @briligg Rice only [reports](http://www.sciencemag.org/content/339/6116/182.full.pdf) tensile strengths of 0.2 GPa, giving them a specific strength of less than 200 kN.m/kg.

Comment: @2012rcampion well sure, but it's still early days.

Comment: @briligg 2012rcampion's answer identifies that cable strength isn't the only problem. Peak black body temperature at 939 MW/m² (my calculations for 0 altitude standard datum) is 11,345 K, or about the same flux as for laser material hardening. Even on Olympus Mons, black body temperature would be 7,200 K. Kevlar would melt and conductive CNT would generate a whole lot of triboelectric charge. Point is, that even if we could make such a cable, we couldn't attach anything of much use at its end. Well, maybe diamonds. I'd be fine with those. :)

Comment: @TildalWave - ah. woops. Let me take that back out of the text then. Wait, but the first part of it mentions specific strength. That is the part I was looking at there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We can compute the power required to maintain speed as:

$$
P=\frac{C_D}2\rho A v^3
$$

Assuming the hypersonic drag coefficient is around $1$ and that the atmospheric density is $1\%$ of Earth's, we get:

$$
\frac P A=\frac 1 2\times 0.01225~\text{kg}/\text{m}^3\times\left(5.0~\text{km}/\text{s}\right)^3 = 780~\text{MW}/\text{m}^2
$$

Even on Mars the atmosphere is far too thick to achieve escape velocity inside the atmosphere.

The linked paper uses a power estimate of $100~\text{kW}$, meaning the largest payload you could launch would have a fairing diameter of around $1~\text{cm}$.  That's not even accounting for the drag from the cable itself!

The big attraction of this method is that it uses very little power, unlike electromagnetic launch systems, but even in a very thin atmosphere this benefit disappears.

Comment: Actually, you were too forgiving for the mass of Martian atmosphere, because you seem to have assumed same specific gas constant than for Earth's atmosphere. At standard datum, I get [0.01503 kg/m³](https://encrypted.google.com/#q=%280.699+*+e^%28-0.00009+*+0%29%29+%2F+%280.1921+*+%28%28-31+-+0.000998+*+0%29+%2B+273.1%29%29) or 939 MW/m² (replace those two 0's in the link with any altitude in meters). It gets a lot better at the top of Olympus Mons (21,229 m) tho, about  152 MW/m². I used [this atmospheric model](https://www.grc.nasa.gov/WWW/K-12/airplane/atmosmrm.html) as input.

Comment: Randall Munroe's model is a disk. I believe this model is wrong for a tether. A tether would be tapered, the thickest portion at the hub and thinnest at the fast moving end. Exactly the opposite of a disk.

Comment: @HopDavid After thinking about it for a little, I realized you're right.  He uses the equation to calculate the strength of a tether, but the equation isn't valid anymore.  For a cable of constant cross-section, the maximum speed is raised by a factor of $\sqrt{2}$.  A tapered cable can achieve any speed, but the required thickness increases too quickly with any real material (just like a space elevator cable).  I've added my derivations to the question.

Comment: This is an excellent treatment of the cable issue, one I will have to pore over in detail. But I sort of feel it could get overlooked due to the fact the question didn´t focus on the cable at all. I have an itch to ask another question that specifically focuses on sling launcher cables so this gets the attention it deserves. What do you think? You´d need to move your answer. It might bear discussing in chat.

Comment: @briligg I'd be fine with moving the cable calculations to a new question while leaving the drag calculations here.

Comment: okay, I've posted a new question. It may mean some expansion is needed, as I presented the Moon as the test case, but that seems like a good way to make it more useful. By the way, it was only because TildalWave twigged me to what it meant that I understood the problem with the drag. I accepted your answer because the numbers show it is a non-starter, but it would be more meaningful to me, and I imagine many others, if you expanded on that by explaining what would actually happen if a cable was spun with that kind of energy.

Comment: $A(0) = \frac{m}{R}\frac{v^2}{\sigma_\text{max}}\exp\left\{\left(\frac v{\sqrt{\sigma_\text{max}/\rho}}\right)^2\right\}$ OK - plugging in 2.5e7 (meters/sec)^2 for v^2 and 3.62e9 pascals and 1600 meters/sec I get 120 square meters x m/kg x m/R. Where did that 11000 cm^3 come from?

Comment: @HopDavid Looks like I made a transcription error, there should be a 1/2 inside the exponent.  You should get around 1 m^3/kg if you redo the calculation.

Comment: @HopDavid I've redone the analysis a little and moved it to [this answer](http://space.stackexchange.com/a/8960/8996), It should be more correct and slightly easier to follow.

Comment: I'm still clinging to a sling on top of Olympus Mons. Not escape velocity or even orbital but maybe something that can substantially reduce propellent mass fraction needed for leaving Mars. Is a drag coefficient of 1 too high? I know drag coefficient drops after you go past mach 1. And if the tether is a flat ribbon, ballistic coefficient will drop since a smaller cross section is presented to the atmosphere.

Comment: @Hop I'll let you know after I finish AE312 (compressible flow) next semester... in the meantime you may want someone more learned to take a look.

Comment: We could put this on Olympus Mons ;).